# Plugin that lets me "reset" second language to match primary language, per entry

Tags: localization, multi-site

I am running a multisite install with two languages: Norwegian and English.

Sometimes I copy an existing entry to use as a template for the next entry. In those cases I would like to fill in the Norwegian text first, and then click something like "reset English to match Norwegian" to transfer the Norwegian text to the English one, so I can start the translation process.

Is there a plugin that lets me do this?